# Mongeez - Adding user to database

Tags: java, javascript, mongodb

I'm testing Mongeez, but am having trouble adding a user to the DB system.users collection.

My code is:

MongeezTest.java

```
Mongeez mongeez = new Mongeez();
mongeez.setFile(new ClassPathResource("mongeez.xml"));
mongeez.setMongo(new Mongo("127.0.0.1", 27018));
mongeez.setDbName("MongeezTest");
mongeez.setAuth(new MongoAuth("admin", "admin"));
mongeez.process();
```

test.javascript

```
// changeset mlysaght:ChangeSet-1
db.organization.insert({
    "Name" : "10Gen", "Location" : "NYC", DateFounded : {}
});
db.organization.insert({
    "Name" : "SecondMarket", "Location" : "NYC", DateFounded : {"Year" : 2004, "Month" : 05, "day" :04}
});
```

When I run my code I get:

> Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.CommandResult$CommandFailure:
>   command failed [getlasterror]: { "serverUsed" : "/127.0.0.1:27018" ,
>   "errmsg" : "need to login" , "ok" : 0.0}

For further details:

- I have a MongoDB instance with active authentication.
- Using uMongo, after running my Mongeez application I see that the DB gets created. If I manually add a user to the MongeezTest database, and rerun my application, the JS code gets executed.

How do I solve this?

Thanks